# A way for shinylive integration for serverless Quarto R Dashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard, quarto, r-shinylive

In recent months there's been significant development in [Quarto Dashboards](https://quarto.org/docs/dashboards/), and [Shinylive integration in Quarto](https://github.com/coatless-quarto/r-shinylive-demo). However, I can't seem to find any resources on how to integrate Shinylive specifically within a Quarto Dashboard running a Shiny application. As these dashboards use a slightly different structure from standard Shiny apps, I am unsure how to proceed / whether this is possible at all.

I tried following the steps outlined on [r-shinylive-demo](https://github.com/coatless-quarto/r-shinylive-demo?tab=readme-ov-file) but these do not apply to Quarto Dashboards.